What are these resistors used in this flyback converter?
I'm new to designing flyback converters. I noticed resistors connecting the primary and auxillary coils. Can somebody explain the usage of these resistors for me.
The IC in this schematic is a CR1510. Its power input for Vcc is 11-15V.


They are used to provide the correct power supply voltage to the CR1510

The resistors power the IC initially, before switching start. (After switching starts, the IC is powered by the third winding, the one at the bottom.)
Spec sheet

That surely helps me on this topic, thank you for your explanation!
